# Pros and Cons of Humans Having Hobbit Soles

Tags: science-based, biology, humans, adaptability

Yes, hobbit feet have been popularly described as hairy.  But they are also described as having thick, leathery soles.  Of course, this is fantasy, but what if this were real-life?  What are the pros and cons of humans having the thick, leathery soles on their feet?

Comment: ? Humans who go barefoot *do* have thick, leathery soles. Humans went barefoot for hundres of thousands of years, walking on their thick leathery soles around the world, from Africa to Europe to Asia to the Americas and Australia. (And body care shops sell pieces of natural or artifical pumice expressly for the purpose of gently rasping the soles of our feet in order to prevent them from becoming leathery.)

Comment: Yes. I've been searching for footage I saw long ago of islanders who can walk across razor-sharp volcanic rocks on their native volcanic island. They do it from an early age and suffer no ill-effects. I'll continue searching tomorrow.

Comment: I need to agree with folks on this one. Here's a couple references about practices, positive and negatives, etc. https://www.healthline.com/health/walking-barefoot and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barefoot

Comment: Wouldn't this simply result in wearing shoes later in life, and depend strongly on the tech level of the community? The first brick or piece of steel dropped on toes would be the beginning of the end of simply going barefoot anywhere other than inside your own home - and a strong cultural belief in the west today is that being barefoot in public is too disease-prone to really allow (and it's a strong cultural taboo, even the thought of going barefoot in a friend's house is kinda icky...).

Comment: @JBH Funny thing is that our modern problems with people going barefoot is because modern feet stink because... they are kept inside of shoes all day long and all the sweat etc. makes for a nice cheese. Then again, the problem with walking barefoot everywhere is that your feet actually do get dirty and you cannot just leave them at the door when you enter your friends house. Likely why many cultures had (and partially still have) such a focus on washing your feet as an important component to be done at multiple occasions.

Comment: @FrankHopkins Another way to fix that problem is to do the reverse of what we currently do, and only put on shoes (or socks perhaps) when you go indoors, and otherwise go around without foot coverings. Then the socks can contain any dirt you picked up while outside. This is sort of done in some cultures where you will take off your own shoes and put on slippers when going into someone else's home

Comment: @KevinWells I'd prefer shoe socks (or would they be sock shoes?) before that. Because outdoors has stuff like ringworm.

Comment: @DKNguyen anything that is protective and easily washable between uses would be fine. Preferably something with a bit of traction to prevent slipping and falling

Comment: My soles are almost like that, splinters only itch and legos don't hurt too much.

Answer (score 18):

**Nothing we don't already have**

My father hates shoes and as a result has hobbit feet already. Pros is the savings on footware. Cons are the cracked heels and when he does have to wear shoes, finding a shoe that fits is impossible and has to be custom made.

Basically we already have thick leathery soles like hobbits already and it's shoes that keeps it in check.

Comment: Another drawback I would imagine is that it's "harder" to clean his feet when entering the home - instead of switching shoes (or leaving them off inside) he likely would need to actually wash them. Obviously depends on the cleanliness level you aim for at your home and where he goes etc.

Comment: Off-topic, but --  @Thorne  suggest to your father he check out Xero Shoes  , xeroshoes.com . They cater to the barefoot set; I find their products quite comfortable.

Comment: You may have the causation reversed there for shoes not fitting. I have extremely wide feet compared to their length, so finding comfortable shoes is very difficult, and finding comfortable sandals is essentially impossible (except for in Hawaii for some reason). Because of that I spent a lot of time in my youth just not wearing shoes, and ended up with feet that could comfortably handle most rocks and hot pavement. Perhaps that then led to my feet being even wider, but I'm not sure. I do know for sure that my feet started wide because my parents had a hard time finding baby shoes for me

Comment: I'm curious what requires shoes to be custom made.  I can "see" why in my head...but am just wondering.  I would assume going barefoot all the time makes his feet wider than usual, and perhaps the thicker sole of his foot makes his foot have more height than usual?  That's something I never thought about before.

Comment: Adding to this, Johnny Appleseed famously wore no shoes and when he’d enter town he’d often entertain local children by sticking needles into his extremely leathery thick feet.

Comment: @BruceWayne I don't necessarily need "custom" shoes, but I order 6E width (extremely wide), and even they are not actually shaped right for my feet. Ideally I would have someone custom craft shoes that are actually the shape of my feet, but that is very expensive, so I haven't actually done that, and I just deal with somewhat uncomfortable shoes

Answer (score 12):

## There's a surprising amount of research into walking barefoot

I'm a runner and there's a longstanding debate among runners over the right level of padding in shoes. There's a lot of research into barefoot/minimal running versus traditional running shoes.

As the comments suggest, walking barefoot will lead to heavily callused feet not altogether different from hobbits.

**Pro: greater damage resistance.** Thicker soles mean you can walk across tough surfaces with less of a risk of injury. According to a study in the journal [Nature](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-019-1345-6), "people [...] who frequently walk barefoot have thicker and harder calluses than those who typically use footwear." So you already have a real world example.

**Con: none.** The key finding from that study was that people with these thick calluses do not experience a loss of sensitivity when walking compared to people who wear shoes. (I'm specifically referring to having thick soles, not on the choice to go barefoot. FWIW I still run in traditional running shoes.)

Comment: that's half the research.  The other part is the biomechanics:  if you learn to run barefoot and land on the balls of your feet rather than the heel, there's far less risk of damage to ankles and knees.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Is that something you actually need to learn? I'm pretty sure anyone who tries to run barefoot will automatically avoid the heel strike and start running with your toes first. Your body tends to know what feels really, really wrong. Similar to how a person who slouches will automatically straighten to have proper posture when they try to lift a 30 lbs above their head.

Comment: I'm always a ball striker and I do own a pair of minimal shoes. Occasionally I run in them. I know about the research in this space because of my own curiosity. My conclusion is that people should try both ways and go with what feels right.

Comment: @DKNguyen If you've been a heel-striker, yes, you need to re-learn your landing as well as general leg motion.  The muscles get stretched in different ways.  There are some instructional videos at  xeroshoes.com (and probably places named things like "barefootrunningDOTcom" (made-up name) )

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I'm not accounting for muscle weakness here. Obviously the barefoot running muscles won't be up to snuff. But ball-striking when you are barefoot to me is like jumping and landing with your knees locked. I have a hard time imagining someone who could do that just because of habit.